# Accounting for membership in set, but also quantity in event

Tags: probability, distributions

Say we have a sample space 
$$\Omega_1 = \{\text{"alpha"},\text{"beta"},\text{"gamma"},\text{"delta"}\}$$
if we only care about the (binary) membership in set in each event, the event space would be the power set of $\Omega_1$:
$$\mathcal{F_1} = \{\emptyset, \{\text{"alpha"}\},\{\text{"beta"}\},...,\{\text{"alpha"},\text{"beta"},\text{"gamma"}\}, \Omega_1\}$$

But what if, in each event, I want to also include the (real-valued) "quantity" of each element in set, in addition to the binary membership?

One approach that came to mind is to have a separate, real-valued continuous sample space $\Omega_2 = [0,100]$

Then the joint sample space would be $\Omega_\text{1,2}=\Omega_1\times\Omega_2$

And an example event will look something like: $\{\text{"alpha"}, 32.8,\text{"beta"},43.6,\text{"gamma"},7.21\}$

Does this approach make sense? Or are there better ways to do this?

And what would be the appropriate notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want here can be accomplished by using the sample space:

$$\Omega = \{ 0,1 \}^4 \times \mathbb{R}^4.$$

This sample space allows for four binary indicators and four corresponding real values.  The event space $\mathscr{G}$ would then consist of the class of all [Borel sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set) on $\Omega$.

Comment: thanks so much for the quick response, this was spot on and super helpful!

Comment: actually would we still need the binary sample space (or can we remove it)? the real number space already contains all the information, right?

Comment: It depends - your specification was to have a binary membership *separate* to the real measurement, but you could certainly fold it in if you want.